# Finding domain names from IP addresses in Apache access.log

Tags: apache, apache2, web-analytics, logfiles, webalizer

I am using Webalizer on ubuntu to generate apache access.log reports for my site. Webalizer just gives me the ip address from where my site was accessed. I want the domain names for the ip addresses that are retrieved.

Is there any way to get the domain names? Is there some other tool that I need to use? I tried using Awstats but my server admin told me not to because it changes access rights of various different files. I cannot use google analytics or piwik as well.

I tried nslookup but how can i use nslookup on the access.log file? I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the registered domain of one IP address, copy and paste the IP address into the upper right field at arin.net

If you have a bunch of IP addresses to look up, there are other web analytics software products you can use - check out Angelfish Software.